# no wifi adapter found (after boot from windows)

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 18.04, wireless

Lenovo IdeaPad S540
sometimes when I boot my Ubuntu18-04 (dual-boot), `no wifi adapter found` error raises when I try to connect to wifi. after restart, it's working fine.
I inspected the issue and I think it happens only (and always) when I boot windows. then turn off from windows menu, then startup to Ubuntu.
driver is loaded

edit:

`$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` returns

[lspci return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcSzu.png)

edit2:
installed newest driver from intel's website (and not through windows update)
now when restarting, no problem wifi wifi adapter. afer shut-down there isn't

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command when Wi-Fi isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with Intel, I installed the newest driver from Intel website.
I canceled the "Fast startup" option in windows, which by def doesn't free resources to be able to boot from shut down faster (restart is not affected)
[from windows settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u9vH.png)

[answer from Intel](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/Intel-R-Wireless-AC-9560-160MHz-won-t-work-well-when-dual/m-p/726516/highlight/true#M29084) attached

Comment: My answer deleted, yours upvoted!  **0:-)**